# min() function doesn't work on koalas.DataFrame columns of date types

Tags: pyspark, spark-koalas

I created the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import databricks.koalas as ks
df = ks.DataFrame(
    {'Date1': pd.date_range('20211101', '20211110', freq='1D'), 
     'Date2': pd.date_range('20201101', '20201110', freq='1D')})
df
```

Out[0]:

|  | Date1 | Date2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-11-01 | 2020-11-01 |
| 1 | 2021-11-02 | 2020-11-02 |
| 2 | 2021-11-03 | 2020-11-03 |
| 3 | 2021-11-04 | 2020-11-04 |
| 4 | 2021-11-05 | 2020-11-05 |
| 5 | 2021-11-06 | 2020-11-06 |
| 6 | 2021-11-07 | 2020-11-07 |
| 7 | 2021-11-08 | 2020-11-08 |
| 8 | 2021-11-09 | 2020-11-09 |
| 9 | 2021-11-10 | 2020-11-10 |

When trying to get the minimum of `Date1` I get the correct result:

```
df.Date1.min()
```

Out[1]:

```
Timestamp('2021-11-01 00:00:00')
```

Also, when trying to get the minimum values of each row the correct result is returned:

```
df.min(axis=1)
```

Out[2]:

```
0   2020-11-01
1   2020-11-02
2   2020-11-03
3   2020-11-04
4   2020-11-05
5   2020-11-06
6   2020-11-07
7   2020-11-08
8   2020-11-09
9   2020-11-10
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

However, using the same functions on columns fails:

```
df.min(axis=0)
```

Out[3]:

```
Series([], dtype: float64)
```

Does anyone know why this is and if there's an elegant way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a bug in the code, but since then Koalas was merged with pyspark and the pandas on spark API was born. More information [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-34849).

Using spark 3.2.0 and above, one needs to replace

```
import databricks.koalas as ks
```

With

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
```

and replace `ks.DataFrame` with `ps.DataFrame`. This completely eliminates the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df.apply(min, axis=0)
```

Out[1]:

```
Date1   2021-11-01
Date2   2020-11-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```